# (Absolute) convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{3^k+2}{4^k -6}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We want to check if the following sequence converges (absolutely):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{3^k+2}{4^k -6}$$

Since we have $(-1)^k$, we can use the Leibniz criterion.

We have to prove that $a_n$ is a null sequence and that it is monotonically decreasing.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{3^k+2}{4^k-6} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{3}{4})^k + \frac{2}{4^k}}{1 - \frac{6}{4^k}} = 0$$

To prove that it is monotonous decreasing, we have to show $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$

$$a_n \geq a_{n+1} \\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{3^k+2}{4^k-6} \geq \frac{3^{k+1} +2}{4^{k+1}-6} $$

But how do we continue from here?

Comment: Does Leibniz criterion really deduce absolute convergence? For the sum you are considering, one can get away with some simple estimates. Notice that for all $k \geq 1$ we have, say, $3^k + 2 \leq 2 \cdot 3^k$. Can you find a similar estimate for the denominator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Lionel Ricci's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496216/absolute-convergence-of-sum-k-1n-1k-frac3k24k-6#comment9433836_4496216) indicates, rather than trying to use the Leibniz criterion (note that, as described in [Leibniz Criterion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html), this criterion (also called the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)) only indicates the series converges, *not* that it necessarily converges absolutely), instead use that, for $k \ge 2$, we have $4^k - 6 \gt 4^{k-1}$ and $3^k + 2 \lt 3^{k+1}$. Thus,

$$\frac{3^k+2}{4^k-6} \lt \frac{3^{k+1}}{4^{k-1}} = \frac{3^2(3^{k-1})}{4^{k-1}} = 3^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|(-1)^k\left(\frac{3^k+2}{4^k-6}\right)\right| \lt \frac{5}{2} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}9\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-1} = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{9\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{1 - \frac{3}{4}} = \frac{59}{2} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: Thank you. How do we get to $3^2 (\frac{3}{4})^{k-1}$ and what is this approach called?

Comment: @user1234567890 You're welcome. Regarding how to get $3^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-1}$, I have added an extra detail in that equation. Note that $3^{k+1} = 3^2(3^{k-1})$, so I removed that factor so both the numerator and denominator were to the power of $k-1$, then moved that power outside, i.e., $\frac{3^{k-1}}{4^{k-1}} = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-1}$. Finally, I'm not quite sure what you mean by the "approach", but I'm using a comparison test here, with a strictly increasing series (i.e., the partial sums) have an upper bound and, thus, they converge.

Comment: @user1234567890 As long as all values are defined (i.e., there's no value where there's a division by $0$), then the sum of any finite number of terms is finite and, thus, doesn't affect whether or not the series converges, either normally or absolutely. Thus, one can start the series at any index value when checking for convergence, which is why I didn't originally include $k = 1$ in the summation. Nonetheless, for completeness, I've updated my answer to include that as well.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing me. Where does the $-\frac{5}{2}$ come from? Is there really no other way to do this? This question gave only 4 points in my exam

Comment: @user1234567890 Note $\frac{3^k + 2}{4^k - 6}$ at $k = 1$ becomes $\frac{3 + 2}{4 - 6} = \frac{5}{-2} = -\frac{5}{2}$, i.e., the first term in the series. However, I forgot $(-1)^1$ makes it positive, and with *absolute* convergence, we need to have absolute values around each of the terms, it should be $\frac{5}{2}$ instead. I've now fixed this. I apologize for the confusion with my mistake. Finally, as for other ways to do this, using some sort of comparison is, I believe, the simplest & easiest way, although there are different comparisons you may use, e.g., as the other answer indicates.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is said to converge absolutely if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert a_k \vert < \infty$, or rather
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \vert a_k \vert < \infty.
$$
Notice that the Leibniz test determines whether the series converges, not whether it converges absolutely. A typical example when this test is used is to determine whether the series with $a_k = (-1)^k n^{-1}$ (i.e. the so-called alternating harmonic series) converges or not (it does, but not absolutely!).

To figure out if your series converges or not, one can consider some rather simple estimates. You can check that for all $k \geq 1$ we have $3^k + 2 \leq 2\cdot 3^k$, and for all $k \geq 2$ we have $4^k - 6 \geq (1/2)4^k$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \left\vert (-1)^k \frac{3^k + 2}{4^k - 6} \right\vert \leq \frac{5}{2} + 4 \cdot \sum_{k=2}^n \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^k.
$$
What can you say about this rightmost sum?